# Proving a prior distribution defined by a trignometric basis on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ is Hölder continous

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

> Consider $L_2(\mathbb{T})$ with the basis $$\phi_{2k}(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi k x)\\ \phi_{2k-1}(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi k x)$$

> for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The functions $\phi_k$ belong to the domain $H^{2p}$ of the operator $C_0^{-1}=\eta(-\triangle)^p+KI$ where $\triangle$ is the Lapalcian and I the identity,K and $\eta$ are constants.
> A simple application of the operator on the basis above yields:
> $$C_0^{-1}\phi_{2k-1}=\eta((4\pi^2k^2)^p+k)\phi_{2k}\\C_0^{-1}\phi_{2k}=\eta((4\pi^2k^2)^p+K)\phi_{2k-1} $$

> It follows that $C_0$ is the operator on $L_2(\mathbb{T})$ which is diagonalized by the basis of $\phi_k$, with eigenvalues:

> $$\lambda_k=\eta \left(\left( 4\pi^2\left[\frac{k}{2}\right]^2\right)^p +K\right)^{-1} $$

> A prior distribution can be of the centered Gaussian process can be defined $V=\{V_x\}_{x\in\mathbb{T}}$:

> $$V_x=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}\phi_k(x)Z_k$$

> where $Z_1,Z_2....$ are independent, standard Gaussian random varaibles. Using this series representation a number of basic properties of the prior can be easily derived:

**Lemma**:
(i) There exists a version of $V$ which a.s has sample paths that are Hölder continous of order $\alpha$ for every $\alpha<p-\frac{1}{2}$

**Proof**: Note that $\sqrt{\lambda_k}\sim k^{-p}$ asymptotically. Using also the differential relations between the basis functions $\phi_k$
it is straightforward to see that the process $V$ has $p-1\geqslant 1$ weak derivatives in the $L^2$ sense. Moreover, using Kolgomorov's classical continuity theorem it can be shown that this $(p-1)$ th derivative has a version with sample paths that are Hölder continuous of order $\gamma$ for every $\gamma<\frac{1}{2}$. Combining this we see that $V$ has a version of $\alpha$-Hölder sample paths, for every $\alpha<p-\frac{1}{2}$. In particular, it holds that all the mass of the prior $\Pi$ is concentrated on $C^1(\mathbb{T})$. $\blacksquare$

I am trying to understand by completing the proof of the above Lemma for that I started by applying the Kolgomorov theorem to (p-1) the derivative of prior. For the theorem to be applicable the following condition must be verified:

\begin{equation}\mathbb {E} [d(X_{t},X_{s})^{\alpha }]\leq K|t-s|^{1+\beta }\end{equation}

given $X:[0,\infty)\times \Omega\to S$

For this case I picked up two distincted point $x,y$ and then $E(||\nabla^{p-1}V_x-\nabla^{p-1}V_y||^2)\leqslant \langle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(x)Z_k-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(y)Z_k ,\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(x)Z_k-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(y)Z_k \rangle\langle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(x)Z_k-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(y)Z_k ,\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(x)Z_k-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt{\lambda_k}(2\pi k)^{p-1}\phi_k(y)Z_k \rangle$

I do not know how to compute the above and get an expression similar to $K|t-s|^{1+\beta }$.

**Question**:

Can someone help me complete the proof? How can the author deduce that $V$ is Hölder continuous if its $p-1$ th derivative is?

Thanks in advance!

If there is a need for more details I will be very happy to update my question.